# TFS Work Items user name comments

Tags: tfs, workitem

I am using TFS to add work items. I am often using comments (Acceptance Criteria). is there a way for visual studio to automatically add my username and current date to the comment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can see these details under the History area, All Changes tab.
Usually the later comments should be added only in the History area.